# Sony VAIO problem using WLAN VGN-N11S

Tags: wireless, vaio

I am not able to have wireless running with my xubuntu 16.04. (please note that DESACTIVADO means DISABLED in spanish!)

Thanks in advance for your support!

`armand@cratos:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network

       descripción: Ethernet interface
       producto: 88E8036 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller
       fabricante: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:02:00.0
       nombre lógico: enp2s0
       versión: 13
       serie: 00:13:a9:7d:d3:98
       tamaño: 100Mbit/s
       capacidad: 100Mbit/s
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuración: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sky2 driverversion=1.30 duplex=full ip=192.168.0.195 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       recursos: irq:27 memoria:d6000000-d6003fff ioport:2000(size=256)
  *-network DESACTIVADO
       descripción: Interfaz inalámbrica
       producto: PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection
       fabricante: Intel Corporation
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:06:00.0
       nombre lógico: wlp6s0
       versión: 02
       serie: 00:18:de:26:c6:80
       anchura: 32 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuración: broadcast=yes driver=iwl3945 driverversion=4.4.0-31-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       recursos: irq:28 memoria:da000000-da000fff`

Comment: Is there a switch somewhere to enable/disable wifi?

Comment: no :(  (and I remember that in Windows the stuff works well .. ) I tried with ndisswrapper without success ...